# Paperjs group.pivot not setting to new coordinates

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I'm trying to set the pivot point of a group that contains a raster image to the center of the screen to no avail.

Please see my current code here: [condesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/paperjs-template-6zn8i)

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code example, I guess that you just have to set the position of your raster to be the view center and its pivot point will automatically be the same by default.
Here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.3/S/ZVKxasMwEP2Vw4sdCHI6dHFJlwyl0EJphg5Nh7N8sZUokpDkhBDy75VkO22pwXB3fu/p3bMumcIDZVW23pPnXTbPuG5iX5awsoSewHcEFp0nyzZ2o7hWzo8DWIKiE7ynprjEzxAep3vLqYK8895UZYnOkXfMoCG7c0zbthQHbMmVB7RCnhXbmTafT/Rw9EdHChIGhAOpsaGGMTYhtHoJowqKGSwf4XbuSA5AI5EHqgf0wElN3ifQuI7RTnihVVjjKOjEBuTDhLzG4jpLfXyD9LPism+mPEAoQGit7s2vaFI/JvMU62JA/xF6RbsfncFJ+C7ocGG5pCQUqW/oO7ZKs59kB0b12+4tNouN6F0Fd4vbaCukXGmpAyOvZU/5/43WHOXwjwffRSyNOGoPRgvlY/617lXjJrv1GRraYi/9LJkd9ndRp1iw+0E9XKQ6XJ990nBZ9fl1/QY=) demonstrating a possible solution.

```
// Create the raster.
const raster = new Raster({
    source: 'http://assets.paperjs.org/images/marilyn.jpg',
    // When image is loaded...
    onLoad: () => {
        // ...place it at center.
        raster.position = view.center;
    }
});

// Include raster in a group.
const group = new Group(raster);

// Mark center with a circle.
new Path.Circle({
    center: view.center,
    radius: 10,
    fillColor: 'blue'
});

// Scale the group (the pivot point is bounds center by default).
group.scale(0.5);
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately the scale method does not work properly when you change the value using a slider, the results are unpredictable.

Comment: Yes, because scale method applies the scale relatively to the current scale. What you want is disabling matrix application on the `Group` and setting its `scaling` value. Here is a solution based on your example: https://codesandbox.io/s/paperjs-template-5wezt